# Fwrite is producing 0 bytes when writing image file-blank page

Tags: php

I am very new to php. I would like to know how I can modify this code so that the image file is written and not blank.  Thank-you for your assistance. The first code is file wget.php and the second is report_snapshot_upload.php.  For some reason which I have unable to identify the file is being written but with 0 bytes.  I apologize for my ignorance, as I have only been coding for a few months now.  Does anybody know from the two files that I have listed, what I am missing?

```
  <?php
$type = 'image/'.$_GET['type'];
$url = urldecode($_GET['url']);
/*if (filter_var($url, FILTER_VALIDATE_URL) === FALSE){
    die('Not a valid URL');
}else{*/

//}
if(strpos($url,".jpeg") != false || strpos($url,".jpg") != false || strpos($url,".png") != false || strpos($url,".gif") != false || (strpos($url,"facebook") != false && strpos($url,".php") == false && strpos($url,".asp") == false && strpos($url,".aspx") == false && strpos($url,".cgi") == false)){
    $file = file_get_contents($url);
}else{
     die('Not a valid URL');
}

header('Content-Type:'.$type);
echo $file;
?>

<?php
//this file is called by index.swf when a report is made
$siteId  = $_GET["siteId"];//user's id as sent by the siteID var in avc_settings.xxx
$type = $_GET["type"];//snapshot type (text-chat snapshot or camera snapshot);

//make the folder if it's missing
if(!file_exists("report_snaps")){

    $oldmask = umask(0);
mkdir("report_snaps", 0777);
umask($oldmask);




}

//check for malicious $type values
if($type!="TEXT.jpg" && $type !="CAM.jpg"){
    die("save=failed");
}

$image = fopen("report_snaps/".$siteId."_".$type,"wb");
if ($image){
    if (fwrite($image, file_get_contents("php://input"))){
        fclose($image);

        echo "save=ok";
    }else{
        echo "save=failed";
    }
}else{
    echo "save=failed";
}

?>
```

Comment: Most probably you get nothing in php://input

Comment: There will be no input on a GET request to a web page. How is the image being sent?

Comment: Thank-you Alberto, why would I get nothing using php://input?  All I know is that it works with the Camera image, but not the screenshot image.

Comment: `php://input` gives access to the request body, but an actual GET request usually doesn’t have one. You have given us no info whatsoever about what data you are sending to this script and how, so please add that.

Comment: Thank-you misorude, I will look at this further and see if I can provide what is needed.

Comment: Additonal Code added.